# Bootstrap 5 - "Attribute href not allowed on element input at this point."

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab navigation and inside the second tab I have a checkbox switch that collapses and expands a div.

It all works but on W3 validator I get this:

[image]

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" 
            type="checkbox" id="check-send-password"
           data-bs-toggle="collapse"
           href="#resetpassword" role="button"
           aria-expanded="false" 
           aria-controls="resetpassword" 
           aria-pressed="true">
</div>
```

How can I make W3 validate this document while keeping its functionality? I suspect it's something to do with it not being visible as page loads.

Comment: ``href="#resetpassword"`` doesn't make sense on an input? It shouldn't be there.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I got it sorted. No idea where I copied and pasted that crap from :(

Comment: hehe, :P. NW :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
href="#resetpassword"
```

To:

```
data-bs-target="#resetpassword"
```